# iphone map kit indoors?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios4

i'm trying to develop a small application that is able to track the position of the user indoors. I also want to create a small map of the building floor, so the user can see a image of it and his/her current position as they travel though the building. They would be able to connect via wifi.

Are there any tutorials/examples of how to create a navigational map indoors on the iphone? furthermore is it possible to accuratly track the position of the player by the use of wifi indoors?

Comment: No it's the same thing as using only 1 gps satellite. I know its possible with triangulation with at least 3 wifi routers but the results are not very accurate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second question is IMHO much more crucial, and the answer is "not very easily, and not very accurately". You'd have to see multiple APs (4+) located at well known positions at the same time, and triangulate your position from the signal strengths. This would also require that the phone scans for networks **all the time** but doesn't connect to any.